# FFMPEG silence at end of clip when trimming

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to link generate a video with a thumbnail with some audio.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i thumbnail.png -ss 2:20 -t 1 -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -b:a 192k -r 5 -vf "format=yuv420p,scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1920:1080" -shortest video.mp4
```

The generated output has about 5 seconds of silence at the end, no matter where i start / stop the audio trim.

Why's this happening?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55800185

Comment: Also, calculate duration of your video and audio tracks and see, if they match.

Comment: @DavidJashi there's no video input, only a looped thumbnail image

Comment: @Tobi there is an output file to check durations of tracks in.